how to show that if $L'\in \text{P}\iff \text{P}=\text{NP}?$
I have one small question.
If $L'\in \text{NP}$ and for all $L\in \text{NP}$ such that $L\leq_p L'.$
My question is, how to show that if $L'\in \text{P}\iff \text{P}=\text{NP}?$
It's obvious by intuition, since $L$ is in $\text{NP}$, and $L$ polynomially reduces to $L'$, $L'$ also belongs to $L$, altogether implies $\text{P}=\text{NP}$.
But I came looking for formal proof.

We are given that $L' \in NP$ and that for all $L \in NP$, $L \leq_p L'$ (i.e., every language $L \in NP$ is polynomial-time reducible to $L'$). We will prove $L' \in P \iff P = NP$ in two directions:
Proof direction 1: If $L' \in P$, then $P = NP$:

By assumption, for every $L \in NP$, $L \leq_p L'$. This means there exists a polynomial-time reduction $f$ such that $x \in L \iff f(x) \in L'$.

If $L' \in P$, then there exists a polynomial-time algorithm $A'$ deciding $L'$.

To decide any $L \in NP$, we can:



Compute $f(x)$ in polynomial time (as $f$ is a polynomial-time reduction).
Run the algorithm $A'$ on $f(x)$, which is also polynomial time.


Therefore, $L \in P$, and since this holds for all $L \in NP$, we have
$NP \subseteq P$. Since $P \subseteq NP$ always holds, it follows that
$P = NP$.

Proof Direction 2: If $P = NP$, then $L' \in P$:

By definition, $L' \in NP$. If $P = NP$, then every language in $NP$ is also in $P$.

Thus, $L' \in P$.


From (1) and (2), we conclude that $L' \in P \iff P = NP$.
Hope this helps!
-- SG

"Run the algorithm $A'$ on $f(x)$, which is also polynomial time".---- how to know the algorithm $A'$ is polytime? Although f is comptable in polytime. Would you explain little bit.

Intuitively, $f$ being polynomial time means that we can take instance of any problem $L \in NP$ and convert it to an instance of $L'$ (Point 1 under Proof Direction 1). Now, for this proof direction, we have assumed $L' \in P$, that means there is an algorithm $A'$ which runs in polynomial-time and decides $L'$ (by definition of $L'$ being in $P$). These two facts together show that all NP problems can be solved in P by first using $f$ to convert that problem to $L'$ and then using A' to solve it.
